# Expected number of elements in random bucket, where the probability of a bucket is proportional to its size

Tags: expected-value, poisson-distribution

I distribute n balls into m buckets randomly and uniformly. Let's assume that n/m is greater than 1, and m is a large number.

Next, I choose a bucket at random, but the probability of selecting a particular bucket is directly proportional to the number of balls it contains. In other words, buckets with more than n/m balls are more likely to be chosen than those with fewer than n/m balls.

I want to determine the expected number of balls in the chosen bucket. Specifically, I'm interested in finding a simple method to demonstrate that the expected number of balls in the chosen bucket is bounded by some constant times n/m.

Comment: Welcome to CV.  Perhaps a less-complicated framing of the question will reveal a simple answer.  Forget the first part: you have $n$ balls in $m$ buckets.  Let $x_i$ be the number of balls in bucket $i.$ You say you select these buckets with probabilities $p_i=x_i/n.$  What does the definition of expectation give for the answer?

Comment: Or you could select $1$ ball uniformly *after* you have placed them in the buckets and ask how many of the *other $n-1$ balls* you expect to be in the bucket it happens to be in, and so how many *balls in total* you expect to be in that bucket.

Comment: The framing @Henry suggested is exactly the experiment I am conducting (It is actually the expected complexity of a successful search in a chaining based hash).

Comment: Or you could put $n-1$ balls in the $m$ buckets.  How many balls do you expect in each bucket?  Then put the final ball in and count the number of balls in the final ball's bucket.  How many do you expect in that bucket?

Comment: Since you can easily calculate the expectation exactly, the bounds on it are less necessary, but if  $n>m$ then the bounds are $\frac nm$ and $2\frac nm$ with the lower bound approached when $n \gg m$ (or the trivial case of $m=1$)  and the upper bound approached when $n=m+1$ and both are large.

Comment: @Henry Can you elaborate on the "easily" part? How do you get the bounds?

Comment: In particular I am interested in understanding why is it bounded from above by 2n/m

Comment: A better pair of bounds is $\frac nm $ and $\frac nm +1$, and the exact expectation is $\frac{n-1}{m} +1$.  See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the reframing in the comments:

> Perhaps a less-complicated framing of the question will reveal a simple answer. Forget the first part: you have $n$ balls in $m$ buckets. Let $x_i$ be the number of balls in bucket $i$. You say you select these buckets with probabilities $p_i=x_i/n$. What does the definition of expectation give for the answer? [whuber]

> Or you could select $1$ ball uniformly after you have placed them in the buckets and ask how many of the other $n−1$ balls you expect to be in the bucket it happens to be in, and so how many balls in total you expect to be in that bucket. [Henry]

> Or you could put $n−1$ balls in the $m$ buckets. How many balls do you expect in each bucket? Then put the final ball in and count the number of balls in the final ball's bucket. How many do you expect in that bucket?  [Henry]

it should be clear that the expectation is $$\dfrac{n-1}{m}+1 = \dfrac{n+m-1}{m} = \dfrac{n}{m} +1 -\dfrac1{m}$$

which, if $n>m$, will be between $\frac nm$ and $2\frac nm$ since $0 \le 1-\frac1m \lt 1 \lt \frac nm$.

A lengthier calculation of the conditional expectation could be $\dfrac{\sum\limits_{x=0}^n x \, \frac xn \, {n \choose x}(\frac{1}{m})^x(\frac{m-1}{m})^{n-x}}{\sum\limits_{x=0}^n \frac xn \, {n \choose x}(\frac{1}{m})^x(\frac{m-1}{m})^{n-x}} = \dfrac{\frac1n(\frac nm - \frac n{m^2} + \frac{n^2}{m^2})}{\frac1n \frac nm}$ and gives the same result.

Comment: I now understand. I missed the point that the other balls are distributed evenly between the buckets and independently from the chosen ball. Hence the expected number of balls that will be in the bucket with the chosen ball is \frac{n-1}{m}. Perhaps a simpler framing would be to say that WLOG we first chose a bucket for the chosen ball and then distribute the other n-1 balls.

Comment: This also gives you the distribution of the number in the chosen bucket: it is $\sim 1+\textrm{Bin}(n-1,\frac1m)$